# Como depurar codigo php utilizando vs code

Tags: php

estoy intentado depurar codigo php desde vs code pero no logro hacerlo. no me reconoce los puntos de interrupcion.

indicare los pasos que realize:

1. Instale wamp server v3.2.3
2. Luego agregue "enviroment variables"
   C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.9
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Segui los pasos de vs code para el archivo settings.json https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php

Windows:

```
{ "php.validate.executablePath": "c:/php/php.exe" }
```

Pero mi php esta en otra ruta:

```
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.9/php.exe",
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3) veriqué la version de php desde la consola de windows:
C:>php -v

```
PHP 7.4.9 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2020 11:52:41) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. instalé en vs code las extensiones mas populares de php incluyendo:PHP Debug
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug
5. creé mi archivo index.php ingresando el metodo phpinfo();

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Mi Primera pagina con PHP</h1>
    <?php 
        $mensaje = "hello world!";
        $numeroA = 123;
        $numeroB = 321;
        echo $numeroB;
        strlen($mensaje);
        phpinfo();
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

6. luego abri el navegador ingrese "localhost" se abrio mi pagina php de prueba
   presione "control + u" para ver el codigo fuente de mi archivo index.php, copie todo el codigo.
7. Abri la web de la extension xdebug para ver cuales son los archivos que me hacen falta instalar
   usé el asistente de instalacion https://xdebug.org/wizard, pegue todo el codigo de mi index aqui.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
8. descague el archivo que me pidio "php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll"
9. movi el archivo a la ruta que me indicó

   "c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.21\ext"
10. abir el archivo php.ini con vs code que se encuentra en esta ruta:

    C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\bin\php.ini

Control + F y busque la linea de codigo " zend_extension" se encuentra al final del archivo en mi caso es la linea numero 1949 la comente con un ";' y agregue exactamente la linea que me pidio el asistente de instalacion algo que me parece raro es porque los slash "/" "" de las ruta estan invertido, no lo sé pero los coloque exactamente como decia el asistente:

```
zend_extension = c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.21\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll
```

php.ini
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
[xdebug]
;zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.21/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.9.6-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll"
zend_extension = c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.21\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

11. cree una nueva configuracion para launch.json > seleccione "PHP"
    me creeo este archivo
    [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
12. cree puntos de interrupcion desde la linea 13-24 en mi index.php
13. reinicie todos los servidor de mi wampserver
14. presiono F5 ó PLAY al boton de debug pero no hace nada
    [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que estoy haciendo mal?
tengo unas preguntas tambien con realacion a la instalacion:
A) porque dice que tengo instalado "PHP Version 7.3.21" si desde la consola de windows dice que es la "7.4.9"
aunque pegue el archivo "php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll" en las 2 rutas:

```
c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.21\ext\
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.9\ext\
```

y lo configure en:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\bin\php.ini
```

Sigue sin funcionar.

B) porque https://xdebug.org/wizard los slash de las rutas me lo das invertido?

Comment: Paso 7, ya tienes instalada la última versión de Xdebug, generalmente se instala y activa con Wampserver. A) Desde Wampserver (icono en la barra de tareas) tú eliges una versión de PHP para ejecutar los sitios y, seguramente, se usó el PATH de la otra versión que es la que se ejecuta en la ventana de comandos. B) ¿A qué te refieres con _los slash invertidos_?, si es por `c:\wamp64\...` solo cámbialos a `c:/wamp64/...`

Comment: Probablemente solo te falta activar el acceso remoto `xdebug.remote_enable=1` y `xdebug.remote_autostart=1`, según [este video](https://youtu.be/LNIvugvmCyQ?t=154)